# Write a program that prints the longest substring of s in which the letters occur in alphabetical order

Tags: algorithm, substring, alphabetical

The code runs fine and the output seems ok. But my `print` is inside the for loop, this makes me doubt that the coding is correct:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
i = 0
increase = 0
longest = 1
for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        if s[i+1] >= s[i]:
           increase +=1
        else:
            if increase > longest:
               longest = increase
               print ("
Longest substring in alphabetical order is:"+""+s[i-longest:i+1])

            increase =0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#With the help of MIT pythontutor(www.pythontutor.com) and
their exercise code test machine,I reworte my code and achieve its function in any string.


i = 0
increase = 0
longest = 0
tem_longest= 0
max_i = 0
start = 0
end = 0 
for i in range(len(s)-1 ):
        if s[i+1] >= s[i]:
           increase +=1
           tem_longest = increase
           max_i=i+1
           if increase==(len(s)-1):
              longest = increase 
              max_i=i+1
              start = max_i-longest
              end = max_i+1
              break  
        else:
            max_i=i
            tem_longest = increase
            increase =0

        if tem_longest > longest:
           longest = tem_longest
           start = max_i-longest
           end = max_i+1

        if i+1 == (len(s)-1) and tem_longest == 0 and longest == 0:
           start = 0
           end = 1

print ("Longest substring in alphabetical order is:"+""+s[start:end])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this:

```
s = 'abcaakabcdeakk'
i = 0
increase = 0
longest = 1
longest_end = 1
for i in range(len(s)):
        if i < len(s)-1 and s[i+1] >= s[i]:
           increase += 1
        else:
            if increase > longest:
               longest = increase
               longest_end = i
            increase = 0
print ("Longest substring in alphabetical order is:" + s[longest_end-longest:longest_end+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your doubts are right. If you string contains some appropriate substrings with longer and longer length, you'll output them all

Instead of immediate printing just remember index `i` and length `longest` (or substring borders), and output the best string after the loop.

```
if increase > longest:
           longest = increase
           beststart = i-longest
           bestend = i+1
           increase = 0
```